# MacOS Sierra & Kerberos

Tags: macos, kerberos

I am running MacOs High Sierra 10.13
I need to remotely access a kerberised web UI (Hadoop Cluster / Ambari / Oozie Service UI to be specific)
For that I first need to edit/configure the kerberos conf file to add the realm before calling kinit properly. I looked thoroughly, the Kerberos configuration file is not present in the system : Not a trace anywhere of a file called "edu.mit.Kerberos" not "krb5.conf".
But still, calling kinit outputs this :

```
user@MBP:~$ kinit
kinit: krb5_get_default_principal: Configuration file does not specify default realm
```

I am really curious where the configuration file is hidden if it ever exists.

Anyway, I tried creating both /etc/krb.conf and /Library/Preferences/edu.mit.Kerberos with my realm configuration but I keep getting the same output.

I am not even sure kerberos is installed by default properly on this version of MacOS, but I do have klist and kinit commands natively in usr/bin.

I also tried to unload / reload the kerberos service but the corresonding plist files are also non existent

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.kadmind.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.krb5kdc.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.kadmind.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.mit.Kerberos.krb5kdc.plist
```

all give

```
No such file or directory
```

I consulted the official MIT Documentation [here](http://web.mit.edu/macdev/KfM/Common/Documentation/preferences-osx.html) and [here](http://web.mit.edu/macdev/KfM/KerberosClients/KerberosApp/Documentation/using-osx.html#startup) but it didn't really help. The'y also advice to use "Mac OS X Kerberos Extras" Utility, but I am a terminal guy, I really prefer to understand what I am doing and where the conf files are and what is really happening.

Any help or decent documentation is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We've had some experience of this and the 'lean' docs where I'm based...

You can write `/etc/krb5.conf` with eg:

```
[libdefaults]
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  ticket_lifetime = 86400
  renew_lifetime = 604800
  forwardable = true
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts
  permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts
  udp_preference_limit = 1
  kdc_timeout = 3000
[realms]
  NODE.EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = tcp/example.com:port
  }
```

In our case we're connecting over ssh so I have: `kdc = tcp/localhost:11006` where that tunnels to the box/port running kdc. Then `kinit USERNAME@REALM`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication
may be helpful after that.

Comment: udp_preference_limit = 1 has no meaning in mac. it was still using udp unless I set tcp in kdc

Answer (score 2):

At some point, Apple renamed the Kerberos launchdaemons to live under `com.apple`, for example, `com.apple.Kerberos.kcm.plist` for the credential-cache daemon.